# Les antécédents des pronoms dans « sans y changer un mot » et « sans en changer un mot »

Tags: sens, pronoms, différence

Dans « Manon Lescaut », l'abbé Prévost écrit : « Elle me répéta ses propositions sans y changer un mot. » Je crois que le syntagme adverbial est équivalent à « sans changer un mot de ses propositions ». Si c'est vrai, pourquoi l'abbé Prévost n'écrit-il pas « sans en changer un mot » ?

J'ai fait une recherche Google qui donne des autres exemples de « sans y changer un mot » tels que :

- [« Montesquieu l'envoya immédiatement à l'imprimeur sans y changer un mot. »](https://books.google.com/books?id=qYVaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&dq=%22sans%20y%20changer%20un%20mot%22&source=bl&ots=H0xevW8Qpw&sig=ACfU3U1DDWYuL-Krkrfjfi_Gu7LXfwD3Lg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd6_WEuuzoAhUFCc0KHZbrCHEQ6AEwCnoECAcQLA#v=onepage&q=%22sans%20y%20changer%20un%20mot%22&f=false)
- [« Ceci corrigé, disons que le traducteur utilise à son tour la notice de Fontette sans y changer un mot. »](https://books.google.com/books?id=-mIXAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA112&lpg=RA2-PA112&dq=%22sans%20y%20changer%20un%20mot%22&source=bl&ots=fPNUe0wmrp&sig=ACfU3U1duJyYwOx6ODT60ZpxjyRdeAyXgA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd6_WEuuzoAhUFCc0KHZbrCHEQ6AEwDXoECAcQPQ#v=onepage&q=%22sans%20y%20changer%20un%20mot%22&f=false)

Cependant, une recherche pour « sans en changer un mot » a plus de résultats :

- [« J'écrivis, sous sa dictée, sans en changer un mot »](https://books.google.com/books?id=KU9YAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=%22sans%20en%20changer%20un%20mot%22&source=bl&ots=Qq6xZBuOal&sig=ACfU3U3Nwy4rn6r6mAf4t8oivjb1LSrUJA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwicCBvezoAhUDXM0KHVh-Ah0Q6AEwAnoECAoQKQ#v=onepage&q=%22sans%20en%20changer%20un%20mot%22&f=false)
- [« Nous reproduisons ici, sans en changer un mot, nos sinistres prévisions de janvier »](https://books.google.com/books?id=OPYOsiWhc9IC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=%22sans%20en%20changer%20un%20mot%22&source=bl&ots=YTjJRA7cO-&sig=ACfU3U0jGFode_KrbAUBnOJNYBxXvjrDlQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwicCBvezoAhUDXM0KHVh-Ah0Q6AEwA3oECAoQLg#v=onepage&q=%22sans%20en%20changer%20un%20mot%22&f=false)

Il y a beaucoup d'autres exemples similaires.

Y a-t-il une différence entre « sans y changer un mot » et « sans en changer un mot » ? Sinon, pourquoi quelques écrivains ont-ils utilisé « y » au lieu de « en » ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

À mon sens, les deux peuvent s'employer selon ce sur quoi on souhaite mettre l'accent.
Dans ce contexte :

- **y** est utilisé comme adverbe de lieu.

> Changeras-tu des mots **dans cette dictée** ? Non, je n'**y** changerai pas un mot.

- **en** est utilisé comme adverbe de quantité.

> Changeras-tu **des mots** dans cette dictée ? Non, je n'**en** changerai pas un mot.

Pour répondre à la question, je dirais donc que, si différence il y a, elle est très subtile. Je pense qu'il existe également une notion de choix artistique.

Answer (score 0):

On dit *changer quelque chose à quelque chose* pour signifier *modifier*, comme dans « je n'ai rien changé à la recette. »  *Un mot* est à comprendre de manière abstraite comme synonyme de *rien*.  On a donc  « Elle me répéta ses propositions sans y changer un mot. » qui veut dire, en fait, « Elle me répéta ses propositions sans rien y changer. »